# pull dynamic element in single array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to pull dynamic element in single array but result is not showing properly
Ex:

```
$array  =array();
$element="'abc1','abc2'";
$array=array('abc',$element);
```

//I want result like that:

```
array[
     [0]=>abc,
     [1]=>abc1,
     [2]=>ab
    ]
```

Comment: what is it showing? what do you want it to show

Comment: i want to pull dymanic element sing variable in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, $element is storing string not an array so even if you try to get output it will display in following format

```
Array
   (
     [0] => abc
     [1] => 'abc1','abc2'
   )
```

Instead of this you can store array in $element variable and use array_merge() function to get required output e.g.

```
$element = array('abc1','abc2');
$array   = array('abc');
$result  = array_merge($array,$element);
```

// Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => abc1
    [2] => abc2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to parse a string of elements to an array you can use one of the csv functions.  You may then merge your arrays.

```
$array   = array('abc');
$string_elements = "'abc1','abc2'";
$array_elements = str_getcsv($string_elements, ',', "'");
$array = array_merge($array, $array_elements);
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 'abc',
    1 => 'abc1',
    2 => 'abc2',
  )
```

Alternatively to add each array element to the end of another array you can push them like so using a splat:

```
array_push($array, ...$array_elements);
```